# How to draw arrow that follows finger from starting actor to another actor Libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx, scene2d

I have two tables in my game. When I tap on one the cells of the first table, I want to draw an arrow that follows my finger so that I can move the arrow head to a table cell from the second table. I need to be able to know which was the initial cell and which was the final cell (where the arrow started and where the arrow finished). If the user takes the finger off the screen and it wasn't on a table cell I want nothing to happen.

```
    ArrayList<Actor> myActor = new ArrayList<Actor>();
    ArrayList<Actor> anotherActor = new ArrayList<Actor>();
    // fill array with my actors
    Table firstTable = new Table();
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    firstTable.add(myActor.get(i));
    myActor.get(i).addListener(new ActorGestureListener() {
        public void touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            // draw arrow that follows finger
            }

        public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            // if event finished and was on a cell from the
            // second table get starting actor and finishing actor
            // else nothing happens
            }
   });
  }
  Table secondTable = new Table();
  for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
  secondTable.add(anotherActor.get(i));
  }
```

How should I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

```
Actor startFromActor = null; // Variable outside of method

public void foo() {
    // smt before
    ArrayList<Actor> myActor = new ArrayList<Actor>();
    ArrayList<Actor> anotherActor = new ArrayList<Actor>();
    // fill array with my actors
    Table firstTable = new Table();
    Table secondTable = new Table();

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        final Actor curActor = myActor.get(i);
        firstTable.add(curActor);
        curActor.addListener(new ActorGestureListener() {
            public void touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                if (pointer > 0) return false; // For only one finger
                startFromActor = curActor;
                // draw arrow that follows finger
            }
       });
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        final Actor curActor = anotherActor.get(i);
        secondTable.add(curActor);
        curActor.addListener(new ActorGestureListener() {
            public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                if (pointer > 0) return false; // For only one finger
                if (startFromActor != null) {
                    // do something
                    // startActor - actor from first table
                    // curActor - actor from second table

                    startFromActor = null; // do not forget to null-setting
                }
            }
       });
    }
}
```

If you need both directions from table to table, you should set `touchUp` and `touchDown` events for every `Actor` and then check who is owner for start and end actors;

Comment: The question was more on how to draw an arrow that follows the user's fingers and starts from the first actor.

Comment: Really? Just use `DragListener ` and `DragStart|Stop` methods

Answer (score 0):

You can draw an arrow using the built in [Mesh](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/ModelBuilder,-MeshBuilder-and-MeshPartBuilder) utilities in libgdx:

### Build a `Mesh` at init

It is suggested to only build one mesh ( usually at init ) and then re-use ( render ) it during runtime as many times as many arrows the application requires. For the urposes of building the mesh, the [Meshbuilder](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g3d/utils/MeshBuilder.html) and [ArrowShapeBuilder](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g3d/utils/shapebuilders/ArrowShapeBuilder.html) can be used. Example:

```java
MeshBuilder meshbuilder = new MeshBuilder();
meshbuilder.begin(VertexAttributes.Usage.Position | VertexAttributes.Usage.Normal, GL20.GL_TRIANGLES);
ArrowShapeBuilder.build(
   meshbuilder,
   0,0,0 /* Starting xyz */
   5,5,0 /* Ending xyz */
   0.1f, /* percentage of arrow head */
   0.1f, /* percentage of stem thickness */
   10 /* divisions, basically level of detail */
);
Mesh debug_arrow = meshbuilder.end();
```

By the above a renderable mesh is constructed.

### Render the arrow to your app

This step is quite simple, provided a [Batch](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Batch.html) is already available :

```java
debug_arrow.render(batch.getShader(), GL20.GL_TRIANGLES);
```

The position of the arrow is then being set by the stage projection matrix. A `Batch` should be available, the very least the rendering stage has one through [getBatch()](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Stage.html#getBatch--).

**Note:** The mesh parameter musn't always be `GL20.GL_TRIANGLES`, but the parameters must match in `meshbuilder.begin` and `debug_arrow.render`.